# malformed_path for uploading file into my dropbox

Tags: bash, curl, dropbox

Local spurce  file :   /tmp/back/wp.bak.sql
Dst file : /
my access token is  xxxxxx.
I want to upload the /tmp/back/wp.bak.sql in my local pc into dropbox root directory,and keep the name unchanged.

curl command 1:

```
curl -X POST  https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
  --header 'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"/"}' \
  --data-binary @'/tmp/back/wp.bak.sql'
```

Output info.

```
{"error_summary": "path/malformed_path/...", "error": {".tag": "path", "reason": {".tag": "malformed_path"}, "upload_session_id": ""}}
```

curl command 2:

```
cd /tmp/back
curl -X POST  https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
  --header 'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"/"}' \
  --data-binary @'wp.bak.sql'
```

Same error info.
How to fix the malformed_path for my curl command?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/can-t-upload-file-with-curl/m-p/229841#M12494 ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the full path of your file in the `path` field :

```
--header 'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"/wp.bak.sql"}'
```

So :

```
curl "https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload" \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
  -H 'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"/wp.bak.sql"}' \
  --data-binary @'wp.bak.sql'
```

Answer (score 0):

This question previously answers are outdated and not working. Here is a working code which is tested and working perfectly

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer <your token>" \
  --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/file_path.txt\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false}" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
  --data-binary "@file_path.txt"
```